# Access denied error while downloading file using php

Tags: php, curl, download, stock

I am trying to download below file using php on server, but getting "Access denied error"

https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY

I have used below code:

```
$url_name ="https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY";
$file_name = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "nifty.json";
$handle_session = curl_init();
$fileHandle_name = fopen($file_name, "w");
curl_setopt_array($handle_session,
      array (
          CURLOPT_URL => $url_name,
          CURLOPT_FILE => $fileHandle_name
      )
);
$data_result = curl_exec($handle_session);
curl_close($handle_session);
fclose($fileHandle_name);
```

Above code works in local while I am run it on xampp, but it is not working on linux server.

**Edit:**
I am getting this error while fetching the file on linux server. Reading json file is not a problem for now.

The file is available in public domain via below link:
https://www.nseindia.com/get-quotes/derivatives?symbol=NIFTY

After opening above link, click on "option chain" tab and go to network tab in browser inspect tool.

Comment: Where are you exactly encountering the error? while fetching the file or while reading the `nifty.json` file? it would be better if you post the log of your error.

Comment: The first trick to try in such instances is to send a User-Agent header that mimics that of a current browser.

Comment: @CBroe - I agree with you point and even I tried to mimic User-Agent header, but my curl knowledge is limited.